# Add rss blog address to XML file

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, rss

I'm working on project, I'd like to add a feauture wich allow to read a specifique tags from the RSS of the blogs .
I'd like to get address blog from the user and add it to xml file, this last I'll read from it the rss then I'll create a page to present the differt articules read from the rss. (RSS feeds in ASP.NET MVC) .
I've finished the second step, I'm working on the first one, I've to validate the rss adresse first after that I've to open the xml file and add this address, I'm thinking also to add OPENID verification.

Comment: Not sure what the question is - can you give more details about what problem you're having?

Comment: How to add blog rss to XML file then read RSS feeds under ASP.NET MVC

Comment: That's a bit vague. What is the XML file? When you say 'add it to XML file' what do you mean - insert the contents of it into the XML file?

Comment: I'd like to make OPML file to read from it RSS from the blogs that I (or the user has added) , the first part is , to Membership - Forms authentication and OpenID support , the member can add more than one rss blog , meanwhile I've to verify the RSS (if the link is RSS or no -Validate it - #the syndication support – RSS and Atom ) ;

Comment: That's quite a lot for one question... 8o) Try starting with http://aspnetrsstoolkit.codeplex.com/ for stuff to process RSS and http://openidmembership.codeplex.com/ for an OpenID Membership provider.

Comment: I've used aspnettoolkit but I didn't love it , It's too old (The last update was since 2007)

Comment: you didn't get the idea , I'm trying to give the user a form to add his blog , then I'll add it in the OPML file which is hosted in my server , at the end I'll read from the OPML file to get the rss from the different blogs (these which were added by the users) .

Answer (score 0):

So you want to create an RSS Feed Reader in C#... here is a tutorial that you could adapt.

http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial147_Creating-an-RSS-feed-reader-in-Csharp.html

Comment: No , I'm willing to write one on asp

Comment: Yes - the tutorial I link to shows you how - you will need to adapt it for ASP.NET MVC, but the concepts of loading a feed and parsing it are all in there.